# python pip3 has attribute error when installing flask for python 3.4.3

Tags: python, pip

Im using 3.4.3 for a school project but it seems pip doesnt like this. I am working in a VM.
I get this error when I pip3 install flask.

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_vagrant/MarkupSafe
```

with this also:

```
 class DistutilsLoader(importlib.util.abc.Loader):
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'abc'
```

I checked and originally I had no dist-packages directory in /usr/lib/python3.4 but i had an existing dist-packages in /usr/lib/python3/, so I made a symlink from /usr/lib/python3.4 to the existing dist-packages. Not quite sure what else to do, short of reinstalling Python or worse the VM... I am digging into the pip.log but it seems verymuch the same as what I have already seen.

Comment: See today's issue: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2362. Perhaps you just upgraded `setuptools`? Try to downgrade it. Try `pip install --upgrade "setuptools<44"`

Comment: thank, this with the other answer was able to get flask installed on my system. @phd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Python 3.4.3 is pretty ancient and no longer supported](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/). In fact, no version of Python 3.4 is still supported. I strongly recommend upgrading to a modern version of Python, ideally 3.8.

The current version of Flask [requires Python 2.7 or Python 3.5+](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/).

If you absolutely must stay on Python 3.4, try installing [version 1.0.4](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/1.0.4/), which appears to be the newest version that supports Python 3.4:

```
pip3 install flask==1.0.4
```

Comment: Yeah Im stuck with 3,4,3 for a school project :( Thanks for this answer,  with the setuptools downgrade hint and this I was able to get the correct flask installed with python3. You rock!

Comment: @derric-d, glad to help. But phd's comment might have been sufficient. Normally, I think `pip` finds the right version by itself, honouring Python version constraints.